# Spring boot RestTemplate upload file to SharePoint online but file is corrupted

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rest

There is a `RestController` and I try to upload a `MultiPartFile` to `SharePointOnline` using, the `SharePoint REST API` I'm also using `proxy` due to corporate restrictions.

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity uploadFile(MultipartFile file) throws ApiException, IOException {

    RestTemplate restTemplate = createBasicRestTemplate();

    MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    body.add("file",file.getResource());

    HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
    header.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> uploadBodyEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, header);

    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(BASE_URL, HttpMethod.POST,
            uploadBodyEntity, String.class);

    return response;

}

public RestTemplate createBasicRestTemplate() {

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder(new ProxyCustomizer()).build();
    return restTemplate;
}

@Override
public void customize(RestTemplate restTemplate) {

    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT);
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setRoutePlanner(new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy) {

                @Override
                public HttpHost determineProxy(HttpHost target, HttpRequest request, HttpContext context) throws HttpException {
                    return super.determineProxy(target, request, context);
                }
            })
            .build();
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient));
}
```

The file upload is success, but it's cannot be opened. For example if  upload a txt it will looks like this:

```
--raF_ORlUJptia2_av7ppLBeeMcGf5BUr
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 159

--38dc5323d6b92b5c14c33fade0178306
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.txt"

blablalblalalal
--38dc5323d6b92b5c14c33fade0178306--

--raF_ORlUJptia2_av7ppLBeeMcGf5BUr--
```

If I upload an `xlsx` it's simply just not open, it shows 'File Format and Extension Don't Match' error.

I try to convert the `MultiPartFile` to simple `File` with this method:

```
public File convertFile(MultipartFile file) {

    File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());

    try {
        convFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile);
        fos.write(file.getBytes());
        fos.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return convFile;
}
```

and change the controller to:

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
body.add("file",convertFile(file));
```

But the same thing happens.

How can I upload file with `RestTemplate`?

This is a sample request to the `SharePoint REST API` and based on documentation the endpoint should receive a `array buffer`

```
POST https://{site_url}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name')/Files/add(url='a.txt',overwrite=true)
Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
Content-Length: {length of request body as integer}
X-RequestDigest: "{form_digest_value}"

"Contents of file"
```

This is what i can see in the https log: [http log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ffGy9lnqvxatlYStlDpAsa9XCCP_-1fD/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: your code look right, could you add the code for another service. the one that receives the file?

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t add, because it is a Microsoft SharePoint REST endpoint. Updated my question with a sample request.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to remove `MultiValueMap` and replace with:

```
HttpEntity<byte[]> entity = new HttpEntity<>(file.getBytes(), spoHelperService.createAuthHeader(authToken));

ResponseEntity<SpoUploadResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(uploadFileUrl, HttpMethod.POST,
        entity, SpoUploadResponse.class);
```